# Android How to convert Hex String to int but remain 0x

Tags: android

I has a Hex String like "0xff"

I want to convert the String to int

but remain the part of "0x"

such as

```
String hex = "0x32";

int convert = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
```

the result of convert = 50

but what i want is directly convert the hex to int like:

```
convert = 0x32
```

How should i do?

Edit:

I have an variable hex like

```
String Hex = "0x32"
```

Now I want to parse it to int value but i want the int result is

```
int convert = 0x32
```

My question is which method can help me convert the hex String directly to int like

```
String hex = "0x32"

int convert = hex do some thing but result will be convert = 0x32
```

Comment: Not sure what is being asked here.  `0x32` and `50` are exactly the same integer.

Comment: both are same thing. you can get the hex value back by Integer.toHexString(50)

Comment: If I am not misunderstood your question, you "cannot" store the value as Hex for integer, because Hex is just another representation of a number (same for binary and octal). Perhaps what you want is a function to write an `int` as Hex with format `0x##`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to confuse the value of an integer with its representation as a string. For example the integer value twelve can be represented in various ways, decimal 12, octal 14, hex c, binary 1100, roman XII, are just a few of the possible representations.

An `int` in Java just stores the value. Representations come into play when you convert the value to a string or vice versa.